# Recursively apply lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

Out of curiosity, I was testing whether recursive lapply gives me the same result as applying the function manually. I found out that lapply behaves erratically. So, here's what I did:

**Example 1:**

```
m<-c(2,3,4)
n<-c(5,6,3)
o<-c(1,1,1.5)
dc<-data.frame(m,n,o)
```

Now, let's analyze the fun part:

```
lapply(dc,mode)
```

gives:

```
lapply(dc,mode)
$m
[1] "numeric"

$n
[1] "numeric"

$o
[1] "numeric"
```

Let's compare above result running mode individually on say "m".

```
  mode(dc$m)
```

I got:

```
"numeric"
```

Ditto for others. This is all good because we have got atomic vectors.

Now, let's analyze another example:

**Example 2:**

```
a<-c(2,3,4,5,5,3)
b<-c(0,1,1,0,1,0)
b<-factor(b,levels = c(0,1),labels = c("F","M"))
c<-c("Hello","Hi")
datacheck<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Now, I would apply "str" function to a, b and c individually.

```
str(datacheck$b)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2 2 1 2 1
str(datacheck$c)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Hello","Hi": 1 2 1 2 1 2
str(datacheck$a)
 num [1:6] 2 3 4 5 5 3
```

This is all good and expected because b and c are factors. "a" is just an array of numbers.

Now, when I run lapply, I get:

```
 lapply(datacheck,str)
 num [1:6] 2 3 4 5 5 3
 Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2 2 1 2 1
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Hello","Hi": 1 2 1 2 1 2
$a
NULL

$b
NULL

$c
NULL
```

My question is: why are $a, $b and $c NULL and not numeric, what we found when we ran str() command independently? I looked around on SO and also read ?lapply, but I couldn't find an answer.

I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use `class`

```
lapply(datacheck, class)
```

This returns a `list`, but if we need a `vector`

```
sapply(datacheck, class)
#       a         b         c 
#"numeric"  "factor"  "factor"
```

---

If we need to get the `str` as a character output, we can do with `capture.output` as `str` just prints the output.

```
lapply(datacheck, function(x) trimws(capture.output(str(x))))
#$a
#[1] "num [1:6] 2 3 4 5 5 3"

#$b
#[1] "Factor w/ 2 levels \"F\",\"M\": 1 2 2 1 2 1"

#$c
#[1] "Factor w/ 2 levels \"Hello\",\"Hi\": 1 2 1 2 1 2"
```

By checking the

```
class(str(datacheck$a))
num [1:6] 2 3 4 5 5 3
#[1] "NULL"
```

we get a NULL as output which is why the `lapply` shows NULL

```
lapply(datacheck, str)
```

---

By checking the source code of `str`

```
 methods(str)
 #[1] str.data.frame* str.Date*       str.default*    str.dendrogram* str.logLik*     str.POSIXt*    

getAnywhere(str.default)
...
...

 cat(ss, sep = "\n") #just prints the output
 return(invisible())
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. This still doesn't answer my question--why am I getting different results for str()?

Comment: @akrun Teaching people to look at the sources is a good thing in general. But I would be happy if people would look at the documentation first...

Comment: @UweBlock  Yes, that is also true and honestly I didn't check the documentation.

Comment: @akrun No, I didn't delete it. It should be still there.

Comment: Uwe Block and akrun-I appreciate your response. Please note that it has been five days since I picked RStudio/R book. So, there could be circumstances where people would have read the documentation and not able to apply the concept. I had read the ?str() and ?lapply file and several posts on SO before posting. Please understand my constraints. Not everyone knows R to such an extent as you guys. I sincerely appreciate your efforts to help me. Thanks.

Comment: @UweBlock I thought it was yours that got deleted.  Plus one.

Comment: @watchtower You need no excuses for well-cast questions. Learning means to stay curious. Have fun with `R`!

Comment: Thank you Uwe Block. I appreciate it. So far, I don't repent switching from STATA to R.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `lapply(datacheck,str)` returns a list of `NULL` is explained in `help(str)`:

> #### Value
>
> `str` does not return anything, for efficiency reasons. The obvious side effect is output to the terminal.

So, the difference is what you see printed in the console window and what the function actually returns. Using `lapply` does make this visible.

Comment: Thanks Uwe Block. This combined with akrun's response really helps.